# parallelization of sequential program and code generation

Tags: multithreading, compiler-construction, code-generation, llvm

*I am MSc student and my thesis subject is   "parallelization of sequential program in thread level to run on multi-core processors". I want automatically parallelize sequential program in thread level to run on multi-core processors with software pipelining.
I've use LLVM to code analysis and translate code to IR, I could extract PDG graph form IR code and convert it to SCCDAG and  partition DAGSCC  considering  with  my  criteria.  In next step I could recognize  position of communications between partitions. 
But for final step and code  generation, I don't have any idea and information to assign partitions  and communications to threads.  and I stop in this position. Unfortunately I don’t  have enough time and I am under force to complete the project.
Can you help me and do you know tools or references that can help me in short time.
 thank  you for your attention and I wish you a good times.
Best  regards*

Comment: Good luck with even the first step of partitioning: you have to solve a complete pointer aliasing problem first before you start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under pressure, might you be able to change slightly topic ? There are plenty of simillar topics related with parallelization, that might interest your supervisor, and might better address your resources (time, performance etc).

Check out:

- Polyhedral Model optimizations like

  - cloog : http://www.bastoul.net/cloog/
  - loopo: http://www.infosun.fim.uni-passau.de/cl/loopo/

Checkout, existing tools related with automatic parallelization, like:

- Omni OpenMP Compiler : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization_tool#Omni_OpenMP_Compiler

You might like to play with [Denotional Semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) topic, and make tool similar to cloog, that changes recognized patterns into openmp parallelized code.

Btw. [ROSE (compiler framework)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROSE_compiler_framework) might be interesting alternative to LLVM, because of it's OpenMP support - http://www.rosecompiler.org/ .